# Not able to draw an array of squares in SDL2 in C

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I'm using SDL2 for C to draw out differently coloured squares based on an array (terrain[something][something]). But when I run it, what happens is a red square gets drawn top left and then the window stops responding.

Basically what I'm doing is using a couple of for cycles to go through the array and based on the value of the given element, it draws a differently coloured square at a bit of a different position each time. I'm actually not sure if the stuff I draw gets automatically cleared when I draw the next one as I'm using the same rect structure.

```
int terrain_print()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error initializing SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 0;
    }
    SDL_Window* wind = SDL_CreateWindow("Terrain Generator",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0);
    if (!wind)
    {
        printf("Error creating window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 0;
    }
    Uint32 render_flags = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC;
    SDL_Renderer* rend = SDL_CreateRenderer(wind, -1, render_flags);
    if (!rend)
    {
        printf("Error creating renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyWindow(wind);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 0;
    }
    bool running = true;
    float x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0;
    SDL_Rect rect = { (int)x_pos, (int)y_pos, PIXELSIZE, PIXELSIZE };
    SDL_Event event;
    while (running)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    running = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = ARRAYH - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ARRAYW; j++)
            {
                switch (terrain[i][j])
                {
                    case air:
                        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 75, 163, 255, 255);
                    case grass:
                        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 0, 181, 16, 255);
                    case dirt:
                        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 74, 26, 0, 255);
                    case stone:
                        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 85, 85, 85, 255);
                }
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 255, 0, 0, 255);
                SDL_RenderFillRect(rend, &rect);
                SDL_RenderPresent(rend);
                SDL_Delay(1000 / FPS);
                x_pos += PIXELSIZE;
            }
            y_pos += PIXELSIZE;
        }
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(rend);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(wind);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: missing `break;` in switch?

Comment: Generally, it is easier for other people to help you if you provide a [mre].

Comment: Just as a side note: I don't recommend using `SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING`, because that will increase the loading time of your program. As a general rule, you should only initialize the components that you need. However, for debugging, using it could be useful, in order to make sure that your problem is not due to some component not being initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has already been pointed out in the comments section by someone else, there are probably `break` statements missing in one of your `switch` statements. However, even if you had these `break` statements, the contents of the entire `switch` statement would be overridden by changing the color back to red in the following line:

`SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 255, 0, 0, 255);`

Also, instead of updating `x_pos` and `y_pos`, you must update `rect.x` and `rect.y`. Otherwise, you will always be overwriting the same rectangle.

Another issue could be that according to the official documentation on [`SDL_RenderPresent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderPresent), it is recommended to call [`SDL_RenderClear`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderClear) before starting each new frame's drawing. The documentation states that you should not rely on the previous frame's contents still existing in the backbuffer, when you start drawing the next frame. However, you seem to be relying on this. Even if your program works on your computer without calling `SDL_RenderClear`, it may stop working when you change the configuration or run the program on a different platform. I assume that this warning was put in the documentation for a good reason. Therefore, you might want to change your algorithm to render everything in one frame, or, if you want maintain the appearance of a new rectangle being added in one frame, render all rectangles from the previous frames in the new frame. Alternatively, you could use [`SDL_SetRenderTarget`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRenderTarget) to render to an `SDL_Texture` instead of directly to the screen, so that you can be sure that the contents never get lost.

---

> and then the window stops responding.

This is not surprising. You are calling `SDL_RenderPresent` and `SDL_Delay` once per `terrain` element, i.e. once per innermost loop iteration. There is a pause of `1000 / FPS` milliseconds between the rendering of every frame. Depending on the size of the `terrain` array (which you do not show in your posted code), the total time to render all of these frames could be many seconds. During this time, you are not processing events. As long as you don't process events, your window will be unresponsive. You only start processing events again in the outer loop, after the entire `terrain` array has been rendered.

Instead of using `SDL_Delay`, I recommend that you use [`SDL_AddTimer`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AddTimer). That way, a callback function will be called when it is time to render the next frame. Meanwhile, you can process events and your window will be responsive. I recommend that your callback function should do nothing more than call [`SDL_PushEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PushEvent) with an application-defined event (registered using [`SDL_RegisterEvents`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RegisterEvents)), while your main thread is waiting for these and other possible events using [`SDL_WaitEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WaitEvent).

Alternatively, calling [`SDL_PumpEvents`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PumpEvents) in between frames should be sufficient to keep the window responsive. But the solution mentioned in the above paragraph is cleaner if you want to be able to respond to events.

Another alternative would be to use the function [`SDL_PollEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent) which implicitly calls `SDL_PumpEvents` and allows you to check for new events without blocking.

Comment: Alright so about the colour, I get that and it was dumb asking about it. Now - the array size is 600 by 800. So I started doing what you told me about `SDL_AddTimer` and I need some more details about that. I made a function `SDL_TimerCallback pushEvent(){...}` and in it I make an event and put it inside `SDL_PushEvent(...);` . The thing is I don't know what should this event be? And about `SDL_WaitEvent` , I'm not sure where exactly to put that. Sorry for asking these dumb questions but I'm **very** new to the library and still don't quite know how to use it.

Comment: @CraigsCraig: Before you set up the timer, you must call `SDL_RegisterEvents` to obtain an event ID you can use. Save this event ID in a global variable, so that it is accessible from both your timer callback function and your main program. In your callback function, you must fill a `SDL_Event` structure and pass it to `SDL_PushEvent`. See [`SDL_UserEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UserEvent) for more information. In your main program, all you have to do now is wait for events using `SDL_WaitEvent` in a loop and render a new frame when you receive the event stored in the global variable.

Comment: @CraigsCraig: If you don't want to use a global variable, you can pass a pointer to the variable containing the event ID to the `param` parameter in the `AddTimer` call. That way, your callback function will receive this pointer as one of its parameters. However, using a global variable is simpler (but considered bad programming practice).

Comment: @CraigsCraig: The loop in which you call `SDL_WaitEvent` should be an infinite loop. You should only break out of this loop when you receive an `SDL_QUIT` event.

Comment: @CraigsCraig: Actually, the documentation is a bit ambiguous. It seems that you don't have to call  `SDL_RegisterEvents` and can simply use `SDL_USEREVENT` in `event.type`, if you only need one event. One event should normally be sufficient, because a user-defined event contains several fields for storing additional data.

Comment: @CraigsCraig: [Here](https://www.meandmark.com/sdlopenglpart6.html) is an example of an SDL Event loop which also handles user-defined events. However, that code is C++, not C. If you ignore the `GameApp::` (which specifies a C++ namespace), then I believe it is valid C code, though.

Comment: The array is kinda big so let's say I don't need the timer, so it can print faster. Now, about `SDL_WaitEvent`. I'm not sure where to put that infinite loop? I tried putting it inside the innermost for loop but that's just giving me a fully white window. It doesn't stop responding but also can't be closed through the X top right corner. I also tried using `SDL_PollEvent` instead and it does the same except a little grey square is drawn top left corner and the rest is black. Also if I haven't got any timer/delay, how long should it approximately take to draw out a 60x80 array of squares?

Comment: @CraigsCraig: If you do not set up a timer with `SDL_AddTimer`, then you should not be using `SDL_WaitEvent`, as that function will block (make the program sleep) until you receive a new event. Instead, you should use `SDL_PollEvent` if you want to be able to respond to events (such as `SDL_QUIT` when the user closes the window, or other input), as that function will not block, but return immediately. If you don't care about events, but just want your window to stay responsive, calling `SDL_PumpEvents` once per rendered frame is sufficient.

Comment: @CraigsCraig: Since you have `SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC` active, you will likely automatically be limited to 60 frames per second (depending on the refresh rate of your montior). Calling `SDL_RenderPresent` will block until it is time to render the next frame. However, you might want to double-check that, because some display drivers allow you to override VSYNC settings, and I'm not sure how your program will behave in this case. If this mechanism to delay the rendering is sufficient, then there may be no need for you to insert an additional delay in your program.

Comment: @CraigsCraig: "Also if I haven't got any timer/delay, how long should it approximately take to draw out a 60x80 array of squares?" -- If you have `SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC` active and have a monitor with a refresh rate of 60 Hz (frames per second), and you draw 1 square per frame, then it will take you 80 seconds to draw all 4800 (60*80) squares. The actual time to render a square will not be important in this case, because it will only be VSYNC that is slowing down your program.

Comment: Alright so what I have done now is remove `SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC`, kept the `SDL_PollEvent()` in the beginning of `while(running)`. I have also added `SDL_PumpEvents();` in the beginning of the innermost `for` cycle. And - what happens is a grey square is drawn top left and the rest is black. So it doesn't seem to be drawing all the 4800 (blue) squares it needs to(at least not in the first ~10 seconds I waited). The window was responsive though and when I press the X,it does close after a second. Any idea why it doesn't draw all squares?Current function https://hastebin.com/piyabivako.yaml

Comment: Instead of updating `x_pos` and `y_pos`, you must update `rect.x` and `rect.y`. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: In my answer, I told you that there are `break` statements missing in your `switch` statement. It appears that you still have not fixed this. This means that for example on `case air`, all four `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor` lines will be executed. Since the last one is for setting the color to stone, that is probably the reason why the color is always grey. In order to fix this, you must add a `break` statement for every `case` label.

Comment: @CraigsCraig: "So it doesn't seem to be drawing all the 4800 (blue) squares it needs to(at least not in the first ~10 seconds I waited)." -- My guess is that it is drawing all 4800 squares, however these 4800 squares (1) are all grey due to the `break` missing from the `switch` statement and (2) are all written to the same location on the screen due to `rect` not being updated.

Comment: Yeaaaaaaaaahh!!! It's working! Thank you so much honestly, thank you for spending all this time with my noob questions, thank you.

Comment: @CraigsCraig: That's nice to hear. By the way, are you deliberately writing only one rectangle per frame? Normally, you would want to write all rectangles in one frame and call `SDL_RenderPresent` only once after you are finished, instead of calling the function in a loop.

Comment: @CraigsCraig: I just noticed that you seem to be relying on the previous frame still being in the backbuffer, when you draw the new frame. However, according to the official documentation on the function `SDL_RenderPresent`, you should not rely on this. I have therefore added a new paragraph which addresses this issue to my answer.

Comment: Hmm I see. This code will only be used on my own and a friend's pc but still I'm willing to fix that for good measure. I actually like the way it currently shows up square by square. So what would I do to render the previous squares as well in the new frame, without relying on the buffer?

Comment: @CraigsCraig: If you want to render one extra square per frame, and want to call `SDL_RenderClear` before every frame as recommended in the documentation, then you will have to introduce two additional variables `int new_square_x, new_square_y;` which keep track of the indexes (not screen coordinates) of the new square to be shown. You can then render all squares in a nested loop, but after rendering each square, you must check whether you have reached those indexes and break out of both nested loops if that is the case.